Looking for a solution to process records in Spark data frame and establish relationship
System receiving single line records from Mainfram system in following sample format

ABCABCCCBCABCBCC

Each record is for example 200 byte length.

The ordering is very important incoming feed from Mainfram system. In our above example the dependent records are

ABC

ABCCC

ABC

ABC

ABCC

A record can hold multiple or zero B records. B records can hold multiple or zero C records. The ordering is very important as dependency find from the order of incoming feed from Mainframe system.

Using Spark explode and split function I am able to convert the single line record to multiple data frame based on the 200 byte record length.

Data frames are like after split based on the length ( Each records are now dataframe )   A  B  C  A  B  C  C  C  B C  A  B  C  B  C  C
We need to iterate the data frames and identify the parent B record for C record and identify parent A record for B record based on the ordering. C record will get unique value from B record and B record get unique value from A record to establish parent child relationship. The ultimate goal is to insert A , B and C records into database after setting up the primary key. 

I able to achieve this logic in for loop but for loop is anti pattern of spark programing. 

Do we have any better solution using Spark to process the records and establish the dependency?

We are using Java programming.


try spark structure streaming.
